# Failed to emit precompiled header for bridge header in xcode9.2

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, objective-c-swift-bridge

My project works fine at first. when I added Notification Service Extension, I got build errors:

[image]

My bridging-Header.h like below:

[image]

I don't know why would this happen? So I searched it. I have read some similar questions, it looks like I need a .pch file. I followed their steps, but still can't fix the errors. So, How to solve it?

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.1’
use_frameworks!

target 'xxxx' do
    pod 'SnapKit'
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'Then'
    pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
    pod 'MJRefresh'
    pod 'Moya-ObjectMapper/RxSwift'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'SwiftMessages'
    pod 'NSObject+Rx'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    pod 'UMengAnalytics'      
    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
    pod 'Qiniu'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'ESTabBarController-swift'
    pod 'RxDataSources'
    pod 'RxGesture'
    pod 'SwiftLint'
    pod 'TLPhotoPicker'

    target 'ZhiMa_iOSTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'RxBlocking'
        pod 'RxTest'
    end
end
```

Comment: try `#import "MobClick.h"`

Comment: It's useless, I also face the issue, 'MobClick.h' file not found

Comment: are you using pod?

Comment: Yes, I used pod. So do you have some ideas?

Comment: can you show your project hierarchy with pod?

Comment: I post it in question, you can see it.

Comment: Which pod for `MobClick`?

Comment: pod 'UMengAnalytics'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162077/discussion-between-jack-long-and-richie-rich).

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I am facing the same problem for #import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h>  but I am manually integrating frameworks

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu you can ask a separate question with detail.